# RecyclerView Heading with MasterDetail lists in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a heading with multiple items on a `RecyclerView`.

I want the following:

Heading number 1

- item 1
- item 2

Heading number 2

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

...

I can do it with single items but not with List in a List.

My classes:

```
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public string IdDescription{ get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Detail> DetailOrders{ get; set; }
```

Basicly I'm having a list of items & in the class I have another list with items.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what do you mean about `a heading with multiple items on a RecyclerView`, [here is a blog about RecyclerView with multiple items](http://alexzh.com/tutorials/multiple-row-layouts-using-recyclerview/), and there is a renderings, does it meet your requirements? If so, you question just is `How to implement multiple items with RevyclerView`.